# Prove that $|\sin(x)-\sin(y)| \leq |x-y|$, for all $x,y \in \mathbb(R)$.

Tags: real-analysis

The title says pretty much everything.

I have found that $|\sin(x)|\leq |x|$, and i think that this pretty much implies the above mentioned, but im not certain.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

notice that $$|\sin(x)-\sin(y)|=|2\sin(\frac{x-y}{2})\cos(\frac{x+y}{2})|\leq|2\sin(\frac{x-y}{2})|$$

Comment: (+1) I was typing my second hint when you added your answer.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint 1**: Notice that the derivative of $f(x) = \sin(x)$ is bounded and apply the mean value theorem.

**Hint 2**: Alternatively, use $\sin(x) - \sin(y) = 2\cos\dfrac{x+y}{2}\sin\dfrac{x-y}{2}$.